# Filtering an NSArray from JSON?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, filter

I'm trying to implement a searchable tableview in my app, where when someone can search a location and get results. It looks something like this:

[image]

I'm getting my source from genomes.com which gives more then just cities, it also has parks, buildings, counties, etc. I want to just show locations which are cities.

The data is a JSON file which is parsed by JSONKit. The whole file comes in (maximum 20 objects) and then the searchable table view shows it. I'm not sure if I should parse the JSON file differently, or if I should make the table view show only the results needed. (Performance in this case is not an issue.). The JSON file gets converted to an NSArray.

Here is part of the array:

```
 {
    adminCode1 = MA;
    adminCode2 = 027;
    adminName1 = Massachusetts;
    adminName2 = "Worcester County";
    adminName3 = "";
    adminName4 = "";
    adminName5 = "";
    continentCode = NA;
    countryCode = US;
    countryName = "United States";
    elevation = 178;
    fcl = A;
    fclName = "country, state, region,...";
    fcode = ADMD;
    fcodeName = "administrative division";
    geonameId = 4929431;
    lat = "42.2000939";
    lng = "-71.8495163";
    name = "Town of Auburn";
    population = 0;
    score = "53.40083694458008";
    timezone =         {
        dstOffset = "-4";
        gmtOffset = "-5";
        timeZoneId = "America/New_York";
    };
    toponymName = "Town of Auburn";
},
```

What I want to do is if the "fcl" (seen in the array) is equal to P, then I want it to show that in the table view. If the "fcl" is some other character, then I don't want it to be seen in the table view. I'm pretty sure that an if statement can do that, but I don't know how to get it so that it filters part of it.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: As of now, this is the code to search:

```
    - (void)delayedSearch:(NSString*)searchString
{
    [self.geoNamesSearch cancel];
    [self.geoNamesSearch search:searchString
                        maxRows:20
                       startRow:0
                       language:nil];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.prompt = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"ILGEONAMES_SEARCHING", @"ILGeoNames", @"");
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    // Delay the search 1 second to minimize outstanding requests
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedSearch:) withObject:searchString afterDelay:0];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If you're not getting a ton of results back, then the simplest way is probably just to discard the results you don't want.  IE: let the JSON parser do it's thing, loop through the results and copying the records of interest to a new NSMutableArray.

Comment: @rhooligan I would love to do that...except I'm not really sure how to do that :P. A point the right direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: How a far have you gotten? Were you able to get the parser to return an NSArray of NSDictionary objects or similar?

Comment: The key to working this out is to think that every UITableView should have a core indexed data model behind it (eg. an NSArray), where there is always a direct relationship between the indexpath - that way your UITableViewDelegate code becomes simple.  In this case, when the search text changes, you recompute this array.  You should leave the original data source intact for when the search is dismissed and you want to go back to displaying all entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* filtered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] autorelease];

for (int i=0;i<[data count];i++)
{
   NSDictionary* item=[data objectAtIndex:i];

   if (@"P" == [item objectForKey:@"fcl"] )
  {
    [filtered addObject:item];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This did it perfectly after a couple of edits on the code!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is basically, how do you filter your array from a search bar string? If so, you can detect when the text changes via `UISearchBarDelegate` and then go through your array copying those objects that contain the string you are looking for, i.e.

This is the delegate method you want: `searchBar:textDidChange:`.

```
[filterArray removeAllObjects];
for(int i = 0; i < [normalArray count]; i++){
    NSRange textRange;
    textRange =[[[[normalArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchBarString lowercaseString]];
    //I wasn't sure which objectForKey: string you were looking for, just replace the one you want to filter.
       if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
       {

        [filterArray addObject:[normalArray objectAtIndex:i]];

       }
}

filterTableView = YES;
[tableView reloadData];
```

Note the `filterTableView` bool value, this is so your tableView knows either to load normally or the filtered version you just made. You implement this in:

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  //For number of rows.
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  //For the content of the cells.
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So every time the search field changes, you will compute a new array, and then reload your tableview. The number of rows will be the numbers of rows in your filtered array.

To compute the new array, you can do this (assuming an array of dictionaries):

```
NSString *searchString; // from the search field
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[origArray count]];
for(NSDictionary *dict in origArray) {
  NSString *val = [dict objectForKey:@"fcl"];
  if([val length] >= searchString) {
    NSString subString = [val substringToIndex:[searchString length]];
    if([subString isEqualToString:val]) [array addObject:dict];
  }
}
```

Each cell then will get its values from the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your json in a NSDictionary and simply do something like :

```
if ([[yourJson objectForKey:@"fcl"] stringValue] == @"A")
    //doSomething
```